# About ros_web_video and mjpeg_server

Tags: ros, mjpeg-server, tutorials, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I know that mjpeg_server is deprecated but for curiosity i was trying to use it whit a turtlebot, I ran the commands as it follows here   [Wiki for mjpeg](http://wiki.ros.org/mjpeg_server) and the webpage was loading and not showing the information of the kinect.

I ran:

```
$ roscore 
$ turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
$ rosrun mjpeg_server mjpeg_server
$ rosrun rosbridge_server rosbridge_websocket
```

And then the page doesn't show something.

So I want to prove with the newest library form Robot Web Tools [ros_web_video](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_web_video), and after installing it i don't know how to run it.

Any lights about this?

Thanks beforehand!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203350/about-ros_web_video-and-mjpeg_server/) by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on ROS Answers with karma: 82 on 2015-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`mjpeg_server` is replaced by `web_video_server` not `ros_web_video` (also deprecated). Is there some documentation error somewhere that pointed you to `ros_web_video`?

You can find documentation on `web_video_server` at https://github.com/RobotWebTools/web_video_server and it can be installed with `sudo apt-get install ros-<DISTRO>-web-video-server` (replacing `<DISTRO>` with your ROS distro that you are using. You can then run the package with `rosrun web_video_server web_video_server` and point your browser to http://localhost:8080/ to see the available topics.

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-18**:
Thanks for explainning this, now when I am subscribed to the web_video_server I see no image of the kinect and the browser (Firefox) shows the icon of a page with a 3 geometry figures. The browser say always `Connecting` and `Transfering data from localhost...` why could this happening?

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-18**:
About web_video_server: It is possible to use rosbridge while you're using it?

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-02-18**:
What is the URL you are trying to load the image from? Any yes, rosbridge and web_video_server run on different ports and are independent of each other.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-18**:
I am using this URL `http://localhost:8080/stream_viewer?topic=web_video_sever`

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2015-02-18**:
Topic should point to the actual ROS image topic, not the name of the node. Going to http://localhost:8080 should provide you with a list of available image topics which can be streamed.

**Comment by [pexison](https://answers.ros.org/users/21144/pexison/) on 2015-02-18**:
My mistake was that I forgot to create the camera topic,

```
$ rolaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

and using /camera/rgb/image_rect_color

Thanks!